# add constraint for variables in java

Tags: java

Can I directly add constraint to the variables to make it impossible to create a new object, if the new object's attributes must meet certain condition. The following part, I wish automatically check that lowerbound <=upperbound. or other something like int lowerBound is larger that 0.
In Database, we have check constraint. So I wonder in Java:

```
import java.math.*;

public class SumAverageRunningInt {
    private int lowerBound;
    private int upperBound; 

    public SumAverageRunningInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
    }


    public int getlowerBound() {return lowerBound;}
    public int getupperBound() {return upperBound;}
    

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int a = this.getlowerBound();
        int b = this.getupperBound();
        while (a<=b) {
            sum = a + sum;
            a = a + 1;}
        return sum;
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [PreConditions](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-preconditions) class in Guava.

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>29.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use it as such:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

public SumAverageRunningInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    checkArgument(lowerBound <= upperBound, "lowerBound should be smaller or equal than upperBound");
    this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
}
```

If you don't want to add third-party libraries (for such small task is not really necessary), you may implement the check yourself:

```
public static void checkCondition(boolean condition, String errorMessage) {
    if (!condition) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }
}

public SumAverageRunningInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    checkCondition(lowerBound <= upperBound, "lowerBound should be smaller or equal than upperBound");
    this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
}
```

Comment: @Abra mostly code readability (it is clearer for someone who reads) and code factorisation (you leverage on a over tested and flexible library instead of maintaining your own code). If it's only this simple check you can do it yourself, but Guava's library bring along many other utilities

Comment: @Abra _I'd say that's a matter of opinion (regarding this particular case)_ agree, I gave my opinion of course, which happens to be a common pattern as well. _We're talking about a single if statement here_ please read the first sentence of the OP, his statement is very generic and he just gave a single example. It may be a simple if when variables are int, it may not when variables are more complex object where nullity must be checked etc. _which don't seem relevant within the OP's requirements as stated in his question_ please refer again to his first statement